# Error with Slick Slider in the Google Console

Tags: slick.js

I'm having Console Errors when I add the following code to my website:

I've attached the screenshot

[image]

Can I fix this or would I have to get in touch with the developer of Slick Slider?

Thanks,
Meg

Comment: You are assigning `$('.usp').slick()` two times. Check in your code.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that out :)